# return a new list that interleaves the two lists but with a twist

Tags: python, list

[image]

```
def back_interleave(first, second):

    if first == [] and second == []:
        return []
    elif first == []:
        return second[::-1]
    elif second == []:
        return first[::-1]
    else: 
        newlist = []
        for i in range(len(first)-1, 0,-1):
            newlist.append(first[i])
            newlist.append(second[i])
        for j in range(len(second)-len(first)-1,0,-1):
            newlist.append(second[i])
    return newlist
```

can anybody tells me what's wrong with my code towards this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with your code, but the second and third if-statements appear to use built-in list reversing functionality which the original problem forbids.

What I would do is determine the length of the longer list, then iterate through both lists backwards.

```
def back_interleave(first, second):
    newlist = []
    # You want to iterate through the length of the longer list
    length = max(len(first), len(second))
    for x in range(length):
        # start appending elements from the back of the list
        index = -1*(x+1)
        if x < len(first):
            newlist.append(first[index])
        if x < len(second):
            newlist.append(second[index])
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is when you use the range function, the stop value is exclusive i.e., the index 0 is becoming exclusive in your case. And also in the j loop the values at index i are being stored instead of the values at index j.

@CyanideTesla has given the code that works pretty well for your problem